# Problem with Defining Relationships in EF Code First? Asp.Net MVC 3

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, entity-framework-4.1

i am having a four models.. User,post,tag,comment.. the relationship i want to have with EF code first is

1) 1 user can have many posts, can create many tags, can have many comments
2) 1 post can have 1 user, many comments, and can have many tags
3) 1 tag can have 1 user, many post
4) 1 comment can have 1 user, 1 post

through google, i have come this far ...but i am sure its not right ...please help..

## Updated Mapping

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(p => p.Posts).WithRequired(u => u.Users);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(t => t.Tags).WithRequired(u => u.Users);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(c => c.Comments).WithRequired(u => u.Users);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasRequired(u => u.Users);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasMany(t => t.Tags).WithMany(p => p.Posts);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasMany(c => c.Comments);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().HasRequired(u => u.Users);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().HasRequired(p => p.Posts);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasRequired(u => u.Users);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasMany(p => p.Posts).WithMany(t => t.Tags);
```

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one User can have many Posts and Post can have single User your entities and mappings must be prepared for that.

```
public class User 
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    ...
    public virtual User { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

If you define your entities correctly it should make correct mapping for you with default conventions. If you still to map it with fluent API you must use:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Posts).WithRequired(p => p.User);
```

Which means one user can have many posts and post must have single user. That is 1-N mapping. For tag and post you need M-N mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasMany(t => t.Posts).WithMany(p => p.Tags);
```

Which means one tag can have many posts and post can have many tags.

You will map other relations in the same way.

Comment: got your point...and based on your point i have created the mapping...can you please have a look and can please let me know that is is perfect or just doing many mappings which are not required...
please look at the updated question for me ...many thx ...